# in suduku 4*4 during checking of row and column color is coming to non editable values of puzzle

Tags: java

```
check.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {                     
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                                
        int nullResult= checkNullValues();  
        int charResult=CheckAlphabets();    

        if(nullResult==0){                             
            if(charResult==0){                                 
                boolean result=checkValues();

                if(result==true){   
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(),"You Have Successfully Completed Puzzle\n" + "Click On New Puzzle for next Puzzle");   
                }else{                                     
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(), "Insert Appropriate values  \n"
                                    + "Accordting the Puzzle\n"    
                                    + "See More On Help Menu for Rules\n"); 
                }                                 
            }else{                                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(),"Alphabets and Zero are not alloed  \n"   
                                    + "According to the Rules\n"    
                                    + "see Help Menu"); 
            }                             
        }else{                            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(),"Null values are not alloed  \n"
                                 + "Insert values in Empty cells Based on Puzzle\n" 
                                 + "According to the Rules\n"
                                 + "see Help Menu");    
        }   
    }   
});

private boolean  checkValues(){     
    int  fstValue; 
    int dValue;   

    for(int row = 0; row < size; row++) {    
        for(int col = 0; col < size; col++) {    
            if(curentPuzzle[row][col]!=0){
                cell[row][col].setBackground(null);
            }

            fstValue=Integer.parseInt(cell[row][col].getText().trim());   

            if(fstValue < 1 || fstValue > size) {  
                cell[row][col].setBackground(Color.red);
                return false; 
            }else {    
                for(int c = 0; c < size; c++) { 
                    int cValue=Integer.parseInt(cell[row][c].getText().toString());   
                    int c2Value=Integer.parseInt(cell[row][col].getText().toString());  

                    if(c!=col&&cValue==c2Value){ 
                        cell[row][c].setbackground(color.red); 
                        return false; 
                    } 

                    for(int r=0;r<size;r++){                                    
                        int rvalue=Integer.parseInt(cell[r][col].getText().toString());   
                        int r2value=Integer.parseInt(cell[row][col].getText().toString());

                        if(r!=row&&rvalue==r2value){  
                            return false; 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }             
    } 

    return true;  
}
```

During the time of checking row and column values in checkvalue method I am getting a problem that is when I compare row and column for duplicate elements if match found I set red color to that cell. But red color is also coming to non editable values of the puzzle. How to avoid this?

Comment: Do not set the red color if the cel is not editable. The solution is just one `if` away.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:
1. If you implemented your own cell class, you could just add a set/get editable method and check it like that:

```
public class Cell
{
    private boolean editable = true;
    ...
    public void setEditable(boolean editable)
    {
        this.editable = editable;
    }
    public boolean getEditable() {return this.editable;}
}
```

Then in your code just check for this:

```
if(c!=col&&cValue==c2Value){
    if(cell[row][c].getEditable){
    cell[row][c].setbackground(color.red);
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Second solution: 
If you did not implement your own cell class, then just store the values (r, c) where it is
not editable:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> uneditable = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>()
// when creating all the cells (I assume that's in a for loop nested in a for loop) if the cell is not editable
for(int r = 0; r < 4; ++r){
    for(int c = 0; c < 4; ++c){
        // if the cell is uneditable
        uneditable.put(r, c);
    }
}
```

Then when in your code just check for this:

```
if(c!=col&&cValue==c2Value){

    // if (row, c) is not a key value pair in the uneditable hashmap then change the color
    if(!(uneditable.containsKey(row) && uneditable.get(row)==c)){
    cell[row][c].setbackground(color.red);
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: could you provide clearly.i am unable to get it.could you help me in detail to solve that .how to avoid red color to the non editable fields in the puzzle

Comment: So you build this sudoku by yourself is that the case? Or do you get it ready to start?

Comment: And could you please indicate the lines WHERE this happens? in checkValues method you have 2 x setbackground(color.red)

Comment: if(c!=col&&cValue==c2Value){ 
                        cell[row][c].setbackground(color.red); 
                        return false; 
                    } 

                    for(int r=0;r<size;r++){                                    
                        int rvalue=Integer.parseInt(cell[r][col].getText().toString());   
                        int r2value=Integer.parseInt(cell[row][col].getText().toString());

                        if(r!=row&&rvalue==r2value){  
                            return false; 
                        } 
                    }

Comment: these are the lines i am comparing.the color is setting to the puzzle non editable fields also.i want to set color to only editable fields i match occurs in row or column

Comment: HashMap<Integer, Integer> uneditable = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>()
// when creating all the cells (I assume that's in a for loop nested in a for loop) if the cell is not editable
for(int r = 0; r < 4; ++r){
    for(int c = 0; c < 4; ++c){
        // if the cell is uneditable
        uneditable.put(r, c);
    }
}in this it is storing one key value pair like (0,3).but puzzle contains two or morw non editable fields.how to store that

Comment: just reposting my part of my anser in the comment is useless. Where is the class or where in your code do you CREATE the cells? or do get them from somewhere?

cell[1][2] <-- WHAT TYPE is this? your own cell class? tell me and edit your question with that codesnippet. And tell me on WHAT line you change the color. Or else I can't help you. The answer I gave you is explaining the possible solutions.